# ¿como agregar un favicon a mi inde.php?

Tags: php

si l ohice con html, usando https://www.favicon-generator.org/, sin embargo en php no funciona, me podrian dar una solucion por favor, ademas debe adaptarse a dstintos dispositivos

Comment: Hola, Pedro. Lo que necesitas hacer es tan sencillo que se puede hacer en una sola línea. Aquí puedes leer más al respecto (con un ejemplo incluido): https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_favicon.asp

Comment: pero solo funciona cona rchivos de extension html, y no funciona con php

Comment: Da igual. Recuerda que PHP es un lenguaje que se ejecuta del lado del servidor, por lo que el contenido que imprime siempre es HTML dado que, por consecuencia lógica, PHP no trabaja del lado del cliente.

Comment: "No funciona" es la peor descripción de un problema. Qué sale en la consola del navegador? (porque eso usa una petición HTTP normal y va a dar un resultado). Dónde está ubicado el favicon generado en tu proyecto? Cómo está indicado en tu script PHP que debe usarlo? Cuál es el resultado esperado en distintos dispositivos? Dispositivos _móviles_? Qué varía en el favicon entre el escritorio y un dispositivo móvil y qué problema tienes con eso? Por favor, ve a [edit] y mejora tu pregunta. Las personas se van a tomar a mal que uses el sitio como servicio de solicitud de código.

Answer (score 0):

Muestra que has hecho y te diremos que tienes mal. No digas que no funciona en PHP solo porque en tu caso particular no te funciona.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

El archivo se llama: **index.php**. Y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Un tanto agresivo esta respuesta

Comment: Mira [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y nuestro [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Pueda. Pero es que molesta el hecho que venga alguien y diga que algo NO FUNCIONA solo porque a el/ella no le funciona. Aseguran algo como que fuera santa verdad. Lo mejor es decir, a mi no me funciona o me da error. Voy a editar la respuesta...

Comment: @OCHOA pues para eso le indicamos al OP a que mejore su pregunta o repase la lectura de [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ni siquiera sabemos si OP usa un framework y tenga que hacer algo más. Deja que mejore la pregunta para ofrecer una respuesta adecuada. Ánimo